# Java - String won't write to file

Tags: java, string, file

I'm trying to simple write a quick string to a text file using Java. However when doing so my code for some reason doesn't throw any errors or exceptions but the text file is empty after clicking the button. Here is my code

```
btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = textEntered.getText();
            try{
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("~\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\File1.rft");
                out.println(text);
                out.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException io){
                System.out.println(io.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Some extra info, the username in my file path is my username I just swapped it out for this post.

Any help would be amazing, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try to use an absolute path like `C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\File1.rft`

Comment: What's the value of text?

Comment: Just add some debug logging to make sure there is actually something in `text`.

Comment: A tilde for the home directory doesn't work like that on Windows, does it??

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine with some small testing alterations and if you supply the full file path:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String text = in.nextLine();
        try{
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/Users/user/NetBeansProjects/TestForSO/src/testforso/file.txt");
            out.println(text);
            out.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException io){
            System.out.println(io.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the shell understands `~`. Java doesn't, the kernel doesn't. Use the result of `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

As a matter of fact your path doesn't make any sense at all. It should be something like `System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Desktop/File1.rft"`.

Note that you don't need to use backslashes in Java filenames.